# Exact same number of page views from many sources?

Tags: support

Several of the traffic sources have an identical number of page referrals. I think that this is way too lucky a coincidence since 6 sites have 258, 2 have 516, 3 have 773. What is going on here?

From our [Site Analytics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources):

[image: image of site analytics]

Comment: Note that 258*2=516, 258*3-1=773, 258*12-3=3093, and 258*24-5=6187. It seems likely that the results are rounded to the nearest multiple of x for x slightly less than 258, or are sampled in such a way that only such multiples are possible. The number 258 is probably of no real significance, and if you come back later would probably change.

Answer (score 6):

There is some sampling  process involved in the determination of these numbers, as [Jon Ericson said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260849).

> The numbers are sampled so it's not uncommon to see implausible results such as several search engines at 211 visits.

For sites with small referral counts this means the data don't say much other than "their number of referrals is pretty small".